# Problems with message notification

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a method that creates a notification message received by a parameter in which the user is clicking Habre a new window with that message.

The problem I have it when you create a second notice, has opened the first or not, is that in this new screen that opens always displays the first notice, although the description of the notice if I put the message correct.

I leave the code and I hope podais help since I do not bad

BUILDING CODE NOTIFICCION

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void mostrarNotificacion(Context context, String msg)
{

    //Obtenemos una referencia al servicio de notificaciones
    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    NotificationManager notManager =
        (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(ns);

    //Configuramos la notificación
    int icono = android.R.drawable.stat_sys_warning;
    CharSequence textoEstado = "Alerta!";
    long hora = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Notification notif =
        new Notification(icono, textoEstado, hora);

    //Configuramos el Intent
    Context contexto = context.getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence titulo = "Nuevo Mensaje";
    CharSequence descripcion = msg;    //Here if you display the right message

    Intent notIntent = new Intent(contexto,
        MensajeActivity.class);     

        notIntent.putExtra("mensaje", msg);

    PendingIntent contIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        contexto, 0, notIntent, 0);

    notif.setLatestEventInfo(
        contexto, titulo, descripcion, contIntent);

    //AutoCancel: cuando se pulsa la notificaión ésta desaparece
    notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notif.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

    //Enviar notificación
    notManager.notify(1, notif);
}
```

NEW CODE SCREEN

```
public class MensajeActivity extends Activity{

    private TextView mensaje;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mensaje);

        mensaje = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblMensaje);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras !=null)
        {
            mensaje.setText(extras.getString("mensaje"));   //Here always displays the first message received

        }else{
            mensaje.setText("vacio");
        }       
    }
}
```

Another doubt is. How I can put a number on the icon of the app when I get a notice?. For example the icon for sms, sms when a new place a number indicating how many have recieved sms

thanks

Comment: Could you please revise your question? It is very hard to understand.